# How do I change document root of apache 2.4.41 on Fedora 31 without getting 403 Forbidden page?

Tags: apache, fedora

I want to change the document root from default "/var/www/html" to "/home/user/Documents/htdocs" but keep getting 403 Forbidden page. This is just a testing computer.

I've made a change on /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/home/user/Documents/htdocs"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/home/user/Documents/htdocs">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/home/user/Documents/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride none

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I've set the permission to the directory, with this:

```
chmod 775 /home/user/Documents/htdocs
```

I've change the ownership, with this:

```
chown -Rv user:user /home/user/Documents/htdocs
```

I've change selinux setting with this also:

```
setenforce 0
sed -i 's/^SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=permissive/g' /etc/selinux/config
```

But still I can't get it right.. still can't see my localhost properly.

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: (And what are the permissions on the path _above_ your `htdocs`?)

Comment: This is the last log: `[Sun Nov 24 08:50:07.247629 2019] [core:error] [pid 74148:tid 140417043494656] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:56760] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/user/Documents') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path`

Comment: The permissions for /home/user/Documents was chmod 775

Comment: Ok. I think I've found the problem already. I just need to change the permission of /home/user with chmod 775 as well. Thanks for asking the permission of the above path!